# Cannot save file using Flux<FilePart>

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have method that take `Flux<FilePart> photo` and trying save it byte representation in MongoDB. The problem is that `byte[]` is not saved in DB however no errors appeared.

```
public Mono<Void> updateProfile(profileUpdateDto profileInfo, Flux<FilePart> photo) {
        return profileRepository.getByUsername(profileInfo.getUsername())
                .map(p -> {
                    photo.flatMap(filePart -> filePart.content().flatMap(dataBuffer -> {
                                byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                                dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                                return Mono.just(bytes);
                            })
                    )
                            .map(t -> {
                                p.setPhoto(
                                        new Binary(BsonBinarySubType.BINARY, t)
                                );
                                return p;
                            });
                    return p;
                }).map(p -> profileRepository.save(p)).then();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation inside map operators will be run only once you block or subscribe to the Mono returned by updateProfile method, this will trigger the publisher to start streaming data. More about this topic [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-reactive-streams)

Comment: How can I resolve it? Some parts of map function is actually triggered except setting photo property